# How does one run "hadoop fs -text ." remotely using the Java API?

Tags: hadoop

Basically, what I want is use the Hadoop Java API to call from local to a remote Hadoop cluster. I want the Hadoop cluster to execute the

It should be roughly equivalent to "ssh user@remote 'hadoop fs -text .'"

Answer (score 3):

First of all, if all you want is exactly what `hadoop fs -text` gives you, then you can certainly just install the hadoop client on your local machine, and run it there, being sure to specify the full path:

```
hadoop fs -text hdfs://remote.namenode.host:9000/my/file
```

But if you do have a reason to do it from java, the basic answer is something like this:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
Path p = new Path("hdfs://remote.namenode.host:9000/foo/bar");
FileSystem fs = p.getFileSystem(conf);
InputStream in = fs.open(p);
```

You can then read from that input stream however you like: copy it to stdout or whatever.

Note that the `fs -text` is a little bit more clever than just raw copying. It detects gzipped files and sequence files and "decodes" them into text. This is pretty tricky; you can check out [the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-320/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FsShell.java#397) to see how its done internally.

Comment: Yeah I'm looking to use the sophisticated aspect of fs -text. I'm dealing with LZO compressed files and would basically like to avoid reimplementing the whole thing.